# Call to a member function trashed() on null

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Everything works fine without basket-add button, but when I added it i have error "Call to a member function trashed() on null". Here is my code:

card.blade.php

```xml
<p>{{ $sku->price }} {{ $currencySymbol }}</p>
<p>
<form action="{{ route('basket-add', $sku) }}" method="POST">
  @if($sku->isAvailable() && Auth::check())
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
      @lang('main.add_to_basket')
    </button> -->
  @else
    @lang('main.not_available')
  @endif
  <a href="{{ route('sku', [
    isset($category)
      ? $category->code
      : !empty($sku->product->category)
        ? $sku->product->category->code
        : '' ,
    $sku->product->code, $sku->id
  ]) }}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">@lang('main.more')</a>
  @csrf
</form>
```

Sku.php

```php
public function isAvailable()
{
    return !$this->product->trashed() && $this->count > 0;
}
```

What is a problem? all pages work fine (I am doing pagination) except 5 and 7.

Models:

```
class Sku extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'count', 'price'];
    protected $visible = ['id', 'count', 'price', 'product_name'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Translatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code', 'price', 'category_id', 'description', 'image', 'hit', 'new', 'recommend', 'count', 'name_en',
        'description_en'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

Comment: did you add `SoftDelete` trait to your model?

Comment: @No.The.Hi yes, sure

Comment: could you share your models?

Comment: @No.The.Hi yeah one second

Comment: did you check the database? `product_id` must have value, probably `product_id` is null!

Comment: You need to check if related  `return $this->product && !$this->product->trashed() && $this->count > 0`. It looks like your sku doesn't have product attached

Comment: @No.The.Hi what should i do if it null?

Comment: @ljubadr worked but now Trying to get property 'code' of non-object

Comment: I don't know your logic, but my guess is that `sku` should always point to a product. If there is no product then you probably need to check your data directly in database and fix it. As for your code, it looks like multiple places are failing because the related product is missing. You need to update all those places and add check to see if the `!is_null($sku->product)`. Or you can update your controller to use `Sku::has('product')->`. This will return only `sku's` that have products attached and then you won't have `null` cases. But it looks like you probably have to fix missing data in DB

Answer (score 0):

when calling the `QueryBuilder` methods you need to access via method names. Acsessing via property will not work. Change **product** property to method `product()`

```
public function isAvailable()
    {
        return !$this->product()->trashed() && $this->count > 0;
    }
```

Comment: still error ...

Comment: `->product` is `Product`. Method `isAvailable` is not scope in his case

Comment: it works with another pages except 5 and 7

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in places you use `$this->product` or `$sku->product`, the related product might not exist, meaning either the product is deleted in your database or the `Sku` model's `product_id` is null. So wherever you're trying to access the product relationship of a `Sku` model, you should check for its existence.